# Why I am unable to connect to remote desktop.?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-access, remote-connection

I am able to connect to remote desktop from mu laptop. But i am getting error when i am connecting it from my desktop. I have checked internet connection.

I am getting error as following.

[image]

So please can any one help me out to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What machine are you trying to connect to from your desktop?  How is your desktop connected to that machine?  Is it over a WAN?  Is it part of a domain?

Comment: @Steve: I am using Windows XP service pack 2. It is LAN.

Comment: What machine are you trying to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

From [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329896)  and [This microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323597), it would seem that the X509 certificates is corrupted.

The below is from Microsoft

On the Terminal Services Server

```
Start Registry Editor (Regedit.exe or Regedt32.exe).
Locate and then click the following key in the registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\TermService\Parameters
In this registry key, delete the following values:
Certificate
X 509 Certificate
X 509 Certificate ID
Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the server.
```

On the Windows XP-Based Client

```
Start Registry Editor (Regedit.exe).
Locate and then click the following key in the registry:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSLicensing
Delete the whole MSLicensing key from the registry.
Quit Registry Editor.
Connect to the Terminal Services server.
```